# C# sqlite query results to list<string>

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm struggling. I have query against my db that returns a single column of data and I need to set it as List. Here is what I am working with and I am getting an error about converting void to string.

```
public static void GetImportedFileList()
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection connect = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\js91162\Desktop\CMMData.db3"))
        {
            connect.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand fmd = connect.CreateCommand())
            {
                SQLiteCommand sqlComm = new SQLiteCommand(@"SELECT DISTINCT FileName FROM Import");
                SQLiteDataReader r = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();
                while (r.Read()) 
                {
                    string FileNames = (string)r["FileName"];

                    List<string> ImportedFiles = new List<string>();                        
                }                    

                connect.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then later in application

```
List<string> ImportedFiles = GetImportedFileList() // Method that gets the list of files from the db 
foreach (string file in files.Where(fl => !ImportedFiles.Contains(fl)))
```

Comment: Why are you repeatedly creating empty `List<string>` objects?

Comment: man, i wish i knew.. im lost. I need the return of that query to be in a list that I can reference in the second portion of the code i posted.

Comment: @jakesankey Ok, so to give you a push in the right direction, you want to only create the new `List<string>()` once, then do `List.Add` for each name you read back, then of course at the end of the method, you want to return your list.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
public static List<string> GetImportedFileList(){
    List<string> ImportedFiles = new List<string>();
    using (SQLiteConnection connect = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\js91162\Desktop\CMMData.db3")){
        connect.Open();
        using (SQLiteCommand fmd = connect.CreateCommand()){
            fmd.CommandText = @"SELECT DISTINCT FileName FROM Import";
            fmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SQLiteDataReader r = fmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (r.Read()){
                ImportedFiles.Add(Convert.ToString(r["FileName"]));
            }
        }
    }
    return ImportedFiles;
}
```

Things i've amended in your code:

- Put `ImportedFiles` in scope of the entire method.
- No need to call `connect.Close();` since the connection object is wrapped in a using block.
- Use `Convert.ToString` rather then `(String)` as the former will handle all datatype conversions to string. I came across this [Here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Programming_Languages/C_Sharp/Q_21309925.html)

**Edit:**

You were creating a new command object `sqlComm` instead of using `fmd` that was created by the connection object.

Comment: Thanks.. I am getting the same error as the code below gave me.... "Ok, so this code got me a little further. I am passed that first error, but it points to the SQLiteDataReader r = sqlComm.ExecuteReader(); line and says there is no connection assciated with it??"

Comment: NICE! Working like a charm. Thanks for bearing with me!

Answer (score 3):

First of all your return type is void. You need to return a List. Another problem is that you initialize the list inside the loop, so in each pass of the loop you have a new list, and whatsmore, you do not add the string in the list. Your code should probably be more like:

```
public static List<string> GetImportedFileList()
    {
        List<string> ImportedFiles = new List<string>();                        
        using (SQLiteConnection connect = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\js91162\Desktop\CMMData.db3"))
        {
            connect.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand fmd = connect.CreateCommand())
            {
                fmd.CommandText = @"SELECT DISTINCT FileName FROM Import";
                SQLiteDataReader r = fmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (r.Read()) 
                {
                    string FileNames = (string)r["FileName"];

                    ImportedFiles.Add(FileNames);
                }                    

                connect.Close();
        }
    }
    return ImportedFiles;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so this code got me a little further. I am passed that first error, but it points to the SQLiteDataReader r = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();  line and says there is no connection assciated with it??

Comment: @jakesankey I edited the code, and it should work now. The problem was that you were using to SQLiteCommands and you didn't associate the connection to the command executing the reader.

Answer (score 0):

The error is about the return type of your method. You are returning void (`public static`**`void`**) but then use it later as if it were returning a `List<string>`.

I think you intended the following method signature:

```
public static List<string> GetImportedFileList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a way to get the individual results, so to me it looks like you just need to:

Move the `List<string> ImportedFiles = new List<string>();` outside the `while` loop.

Call `ImportedFiles.Add(FileNames);` inside the loop (after that string gets assigned).

`return ImportedFiles` at the end.

Change the return type to `List<string>`.

Comment: So then in the second portion of my example code how do I then get that list for the foreach statement?